# Should darood be recited along with the congregational prayers if one joins it in the second. third or forth rakath?

Tags: salat, jamaat, darood

If I join the congregational prayers/Jamaat in the second Rakat and said my prayer along with the imam through second, third and forth Rakat, should I also recite the Darood-e-Ibrahim along with the imam?

Or should I stop with Atahiyat and stand up after the Salam has finished and say the remaining Rakats?

Answer (score 0):

If you missed a *Rakat*, and joined the *Jamaat* late then you will only recite till *Ata'hiyaat* and stop. When the *Imam* says *Salaam* then get up and complete remaining prayer.